# SQL how add a single data element to the top level of each record in JSON query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
create table docs 
(
    doc_id varchar(20), 
    recordId varchar(20), 
    filingDate datetime
)

insert into docs values (12345, 'GUID4', '01-05-2022')
insert into names values (12345, 'SMITH', 'JOHN')
insert into names values (12345, 'SMITH', 'LISA')
insert into names values (12345, '\\Server1\Share\Image1.pdf')

insert into docs values (55555, 'GUID5', '07-07-2021')
insert into names values (55555, 'JENKINS', 'MARSHA')
insert into names values (55555, 'JENKINS', 'BOB')
insert into names values (55555, '\\Server1\Share\Image2.pdf')
```

I am exporting this as a json with the following query:

```
select
    (select 
         docs.doc_id [json.doc_id],
         docs.recordId [json.recordId],
         filingDate [json.filing_date],
         (select 
              lastname as nameLast,
              firstname as nameFirst
          from 
              names
          where 
              docs.doc_id = names.doc_id
          for json path) [json.blockNames]
     from 
         docs
     for json path) as docs
for json path
```

And I end up with expected results:

```
[
  {
    "docs": [
      {
        "json": {
          "doc_id": "12345",
          "recordId": "GUID4",
          "filing_date": "2022-01-05T00:00:00",
          "blockNames": [
            {
              "nameLast": "SMITH",
              "nameFirst": "JOHN"
            },
            {
              "nameLast": "SMITH",
              "nameFirst": "LISA"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "json": {
          "doc_id": "777777",
          "recordId": "GUID5",
          "filing_date": "2023-07-07T00:00:00",
          "blockNames": [
            {
              "nameLast": "JENKINS",
              "nameFirst": "JULIE"
            },
            {
              "nameLast": "JENKINS",
              "nameFirst": "MARSHA"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, I need the imagePath `[imageUrl]` before "json" in each record, so I need it to look like:

```
[
  {
    "docs": [
      { "imageUrl":"\\Server1\Sharename\Image1.pdf",
        "json": {
          "doc_id": "12345",
          "recordId": "GUIDNUMBER",
          "filing_date": "2022-01-05T00:00:00",
          "blockNames": [
            {
              "nameLast": "SMITH",
              "nameFirst": "JOHN"
            },
            {
              "nameLast": "SMITH",
              "nameFirst": "LISA"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { "imageUrl":"\\Server1\ShareName\Image2.pdf",
        "json": {
          "doc_id": "777777",
          "recordId": "GUID5",
          "filing_date": "2023-07-07T00:00:00",
          "blockNames": [
            {
              "nameLast": "JENKINS",
              "nameFirst": "JULIE"
            },
            {
              "nameLast": "JENKINS",
              "nameFirst": "MARSHA"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can I get some ideas on how to accomplish this? I've tried variations like:

```
select 
    (select imagepath as imageUrl
     from images
     where docs.doc_id = images.doc_id
     for json path) [imageUrl],
    (select docs.doc_id [json.doc_id],
docs.recordId [json.recordId],
filingDate [json.filing_date],

(select lastname as nameLast,
firstname as nameFirst
from names
where docs.doc_id = names.doc_id
for json path) [json.blockNames]

from docs
for json path) as docs
for json path
```

But I can't quite get it.

Comment: You're missing a single quote in your data

Comment: Also, you insert insert into names values (55555, '\\Server1\Share\Image2.pdf') but it should probably be insert into images. Which you don't provide definition for

Answer (score 0):

You can join in your images-table on the docs level and get the data the normal way (raw example but you get the point):

```sql
SELECT
    (
    SELECT  imageurl
    ,   d.doc_id [json.doc_id]
    ,   d.recordId [json.recordId]
    ,   filingDate [json.filing_date]
    ,       (
        SELECT  lastname AS nameLast
            ,   firstname AS nameFirst
            FROM    names
            WHERE   d.doc_id = names.doc_id
              FOR json path
        ) [json.blockNames]
    FROM  docs d
    OUTER apply (
        SELECT  TOP 1 imageurl
        FROM    images m
        WHERE   m.doc_id = d.doc_id
        ORDER BY imageurl
    ) im
    FOR json path
     ) AS docs
FOR json path
```